# Tomcat maven plugin - what's the difference between run-war and run-war-only

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

Something of a maven noob, I'm trying to understand the difference between

`tomcat:run-war`

and

`tomcat:run-war-only`

The Apache documentation mean very little to someone unfamiliar with the environment:

> **tomcat7:run-war**    Runs the current project as a packaged web application using an embedded Tomcat server.
>   **tomcat7:run-war-only**   Runs the current project as a packaged web application using an embedded Tomcat server without forking the package cycle.

What is the difference in layman's terms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tomcat7:run-war-only** target will run the tomcat in the same process (shell). If you terminate the shell, the tomcat will die and the webapp is not available anymore

**tomcat7:run-war** will launch the war in 'background'. Maven will finish the job and you'll be able to reuse the shell. Webapp will still be available

Comment: Use run-war-only to keep control of when tomcat is started and stopped.

Comment: @Funtik - such as for Integration testing?

Comment: @djangofan, yes for example

Answer (score 5):

tomcat7:run-war run the lifecycle to package your war then run this war in an embeded tomcat

tomcat7:run-war-only won't build your war. Try mvn clean then mvn tomcat7:run-war-only and you will see the difference.